# How to delete slick slider when on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using slick.js on my website to show testimonials on my homepage.

When the user is on a mobile device, I want to copmpletely remove the testimonial part. This has the requirement that the images in the slick should not have been loaded already!

This is my code to build the slick :

```
<div class="quote-carousel">
    <div class="quote-wrapper">
        <?php if(isset($data['carousel_title'])){ ?>
            <h3 class="text-center m-b-2"><?php echo $data['carousel_title'];?></h3>
        <?php } ?>
        <div class="slick-wrapper">
            <div id="slick-single" data-slick='{"autoplaySpeed": 6000}' >
                <?php foreach ($testimonial_items as $item) { ?>
                    <div class="quote-item">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-4 person text-center">
                                    <?php if(isset($item->user_id)){ ?>
                                    <img
                                        alt="Testimonial <?=$item->name?>"
                                        src="<?=base_url()?>design/img/testimonials/<?=$item->image?>"
                                    />
                                    <p class="name"><?=$item->name?></p>
                                    <p class="function"><?=$item->function?><?php if(isset($item->name_partner)){?> &commat; <span class="entity"><?=$item->name_partner?></span><?php } ?></p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-8 align-self-center">
                                    <blockquote class="font-medium-3"><span><?=$item->message?></span></blockquote>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And javascript looks like this:

```
var slickSingle = $('#slick-single');
                slickSingle.slick({
                    dots: true,
                    lazyLoad: 'ondemand',
                    infinite: true,
                    speed: 300,
                    autoplay: true,
                    responsive: [
                        {
                            breakpoint: 768,
                            settings: {
                                arrows: true,
                                slidesToShow: 1
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            breakpoint: 480,
                            settings: {
                                arrows: false,
                                slidesToShow: 1
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                });
```

1) I have tried playing around with changing the img tags to div's and setting the image as a background-image via CSS, combined with the styles that slick add's to the img tag, as an inline style element to the div. However this did not work since Slick adds too many stuff all over the place. (plus: this is also not SEO friendly).

2) Another option i've been playing with is changing the  element to a  element like so:

```
<picture>
    <source srcset="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAD/ACwAAAAAAQABAAACADs=" media="(max-width: 768px)">
    <img
        alt="Testimonial <?=$item->name?>"
        src="<?=base_url()?>design/img/testimonials/<?=$item->image?>"
    />
</picture>
```

However, it is still not ideal since it will still download the 1x1 to the browser. (But at least it's better I think?)

3) The third option I see is to use AJAX and create the complete slider in javascript. However I think this is quite complex and i'm not sure whether it will be worse for desktop users (performance wise) ?

Comment: You can always destroy your slider if width is smaller than a certain size using $('.your-slider').slick('unslick');

Comment: You could also wrap your Slick initialisation inside a `if (window.innerWidth >= 768) ...` block, as well as a CSS rule to hide the testimonial section on mobile completely (e.g. `@media all and (max-width: 767px) { #slick-single { display: none; } }`)

Comment: Doing both of those suggestions will have already loaded the images before i think ?  Or am I wrong?